# Display or hide drop down box based on user checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, cordova

I am building a reminder application with Phonegap using JS, HTML and CSS, the screen currently have a "Taken" button, when user clicks it, it will display a list of the medications the user is taking in a checkbox format, so user can choose which medication they have taken. Here's the JS code:

```
function show(){
        document.getElementById("zero").style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById("aa").style.display = "inline-block";
    }

function hide() {
        document.getElementById("zero").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("aa").style.display = "none";   
    }

function validate() {
        var msg = [];     
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)'), function(elem, index) {
        msg.push(elem.name);
        });
        alert(msg.length ? 'Why didnt you take ' + msg.join(' and ') : 'Well done you have taken all medications!');
    }

function showDiv(){
        document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    }
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="inner" id=text><button onClick="show()">Taken</button>
</div>
<div id=aa style="display:none">
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Medication One" value="one">Supplement One<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Medication Two" value="two">Supplement Two<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Medication Three" value="three">Supplement Three<br>

                <div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;" class="dropdown" title="Basic dialog">
                    <select>
                        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please choose one</option>
                        <option value="forget">Forget to take</option>
                        <option value="notfeeling">Not feeling like taking it</option>
                        <option value="sideeffect">Worried about side-effects</option>
                        <option value="sideeffect">Run out of supplements</option>
                        <option value="others">Others</option>
                    </select>
                        <input type="submit" onClick="hide()" value="Submit">
                </div>
            <input id=xbutton type="button" onClick="this.style.display='none';validate();showDiv()" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </div>
```

So now when the user selects the reason as to why they didn't take at least one of their medication, an alert will display saying "Why didn't you take (medication name) /and (medication name)?" and a drop down box will display allowing user to choose the reason. However what I want to do is that if the user checked all checkboxes (meaning they have taken all medications), then the dropdown box will not appear, just an alert displaying "Well done you have taken all medications".

And I am not sure how to integrate that into my code, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some of the same code you wrote you can tell if all the inputs are checked:

```
if(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length==0) {
    alert("well done");
}
```